# android studio view --> tool windows sub menu

Tags: android, terminal

I hava Android Studio 1.4.

My problems is that when I open some project I can't see terminal menu.

normal project's menu

[You can see the 'Terminal' menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x374y.png)

other project's menu

[There is no 'Terminal' menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmL3k.png)

What's wrong?

Comment: you mean the ADB logcat section?

Comment: No. logcat is located in Android Monitor tab. I mean Terminal tab!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Try the shortcut alt+F12. Or check the information under the heading

> Running embedded local terminal

or

Toggling `Tools-> Android-> Enable ADB Integration Off/On` then restarting the IDE returned my Terminal Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I hava a self-solution.
I think it is a bug of Android-studio plugin.

First, go to File --> Settings --> plugins --> Terminal --> check off 
then restart Android studio.

When Android studio is restarted go to File --> Settings --> plugins --> Terminal --> check on.

[menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9r4n.png)

Then restart Android Studio again.

Now you can see the Terminal tab.